# Получить значение select'а

Tags: html, php

Есть вот такая форма:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select name="s">
        <option value="1">Москва</option>
        <option value="2">Санкт-Петербург</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Имеем select, в котором есть option'ы, у option'ов стоит различное value. При получении значения select'а:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo $_POST['s'];
    }
?>
```

получаем либо 1, либо 2, а хотелось бы названия городов. Если убрать value у option'ов, то тогда все в порядке...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select name="s">
        <option value="Москва">Москва</option>
        <option value="Санкт-Петербург">Санкт-Петербург</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: А так, чтобы оставить в value номера?

Comment: > а хотелось бы названия городов
а зачем тогда в value номера? %)

Comment: Никак..  POST передаёт только значение (value), но не текст.. 

Кстати, непонятно, зачем это надо..  Если данные нужны для записи в базу, то нужны ID'ы данных, а не названия..